# How to design a filewatcher /directory watcher in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, filesystems

I am new to VC++ and programming. I have a task in which I am supposed to design a file watcher in VC++.

The problem goes this way:
I have to monitor some log files continously; whenever a particular log file gets deleted(this deletion is done by some other program), I have to open a TextFile and write some data and the timestamp into it.

**How do I go about it? Please help!!**

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. That will help you get more relevant answers.

Comment: @Greg - Thanks for the comment. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to setup a system to monitor for file events from that folder.
To get started, take a look at [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx)().

You'll basically get a waitable handle from that.

Then, were it me, I'd have a thread that waited on that event.  Each time the event triggers, the thread resumes, queries for the change details (what file), then perform the needed actions, and resume sleeping on that handle again.

You'll need some additional semaphore or something to use to interrupt this worker-thread and wake it so that you can tell it to quit.  Simple to do: have your thread's main loop do a [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22WINBASE/WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT%22%29;k%28WAITFORSINGLEOBJECT%29;k%28DevLang-%22C++%22%29;k%28TargetOS-WINDOWS%29&rd=true) - the "wake up semaphore" and the FindFirstChangeNotification handle.  When you wake up, check which even notified you, then either process the file change or quit.

Answer (score 0):

MFC has a slightly different way of handling it (slightly) but to do this using the Win32 API what you'd typcially do is use the [Directory Management Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363950%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to set up a change notification handle for the directory the file goes in. Then you can wait on the handle and when something happens inside that directory your wait completes, and you can check to see if it was a change to the file that you care about.

Look at the docs for [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) if you have enough privileges. AFAIK it is also the most efficient way to handle the filesystem events.
Handle or query the __InstanceDeletionEvent, __InstanceModificationEvent or __InstanceCreationEvent for the deletion, modification or creation events respectively and filter the files and target path that you want.

Take a look at the WMI Reference/C++ invocation.

For a full-scale example take a look [at codeproject querying example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387250%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommmend you consider using the implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorychangewatcher.aspx).  This API is not 100% reliable, but this code does a good job of wrapping it.  If your filesystem traffic is local and not too frequent, it should work well for you.